# how to get rows from table that have field and many input values to check against field?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table name wp_postmeta and some fields one of them is meta_value. I want to input 3 values and check against meta_value field.

```
$price = $_POST['prices'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$hotels= $_POST['hotels'];
```

And my query is like

```
SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value
    FROM `wp_postmeta`
    WHERE (`meta_value` LIKE '%$price%'  
    OR `meta_value` LIKE '%$hotels%'
    OR `meta_value` LIKE '%$city%')
   AND (meta_value IS NOT NULL)
```

Here if i give 3 inputs then it will be ok, if i left one field empty to compare 2 input values against meta_value then it will list all rows
Any idea?? please share.

Comment: "if i left one field empty".... do you mean that you leave the where clause intact but omit the variable, so you're checking for LIKE '%%'... which would return all?

Comment: yes, query will be meta_value LIKE '%%' and returns all

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting `$_POST` data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. If this is in WordPress, use [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters. If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: thanks@tadman bt how can i get the post value in wp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$query = "SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value
    FROM `wp_postmeta` ";

$where = '';

if(trim($price) != '') {
$where .= "`meta_value` LIKE '%$price%'  ";
}

if(trim($hotels) != '') {
if($where != '') $where .= " OR ";
$where .= " `meta_value` LIKE '%$hotels%' ";
}

if(trim($city) != '') {
if($where != '') $where .= " OR ";
$where .= "`meta_value` LIKE '%$city%'";
}

if(trim($where) != '') {
$where = " WHERE ($where) AND (meta_value IS NOT NULL)";
} else {
$where = " WHERE (meta_value IS NOT NULL)";
}

$query = $query.$where;
```

And, try using `$query` in place of actual query in php.

Comment: if you're using this type of approach, i'd recommend that you also include a note about prepared statements or suggest $stmt = $db->prepare($query);  https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide

Comment: bt any one can be first value not only price

Comment: @ devlin carnate it doesn't work. we are few near to solve it

Comment: @ jqheart. yes u r correct..... its done. Thank u so much and really appreciated. if u can plz upvote my question

Comment: I already mark as valid asnwer, I need 15 votes to upvote ur answer and i have only 11.

Comment: @Vokamboo, that is alright. Glad to know it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

To compare against less than all three, completely remove the portion of the where clause applicable to the variable you're not comparing:

E.G. to not compare $city:

```
SELECT post_id,meta_key,meta_value
    FROM `wp_postmeta`
    WHERE (`meta_value` LIKE '%$price%'  
    OR `meta_value` LIKE '%$hotels%')
   AND (meta_value IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with your variable assignment:

```
$price = $_POST['prices'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$hotels= $_POST['hotels'];
```

Change to:

```
$price = (isset($_POST['prices']) && trim($_POST['prices']) != '' ? filter_var($_POST['prices'],FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING) : null);
```

I used null, but you could use another value that would guarantee a non-match.

Also, as mentioned in other comments, be sure to use prepared statements.

Comment: meta_value is a string field. It may contain price, city or hotel or name empty at one row

Comment: i've change the filter to a string filter.  you should be validating your POST and using prepared statements in order to avoid injection attacks.